# Drafts on mobile SE sites not showing on desktop sites

Tags: feature-request, bug, mobile-web, draft

When I write questions on the mobile SE sites (I have only thoroughly tested this on Ask Ubuntu) but leave them unpublished, the question is saved as a draft on the mobile site, but I can't access it from the desktop site. I can access it on another mobile device. I can access questions written on the desktop site from the mobile site, but not the other way around.

Is this a bug or a feature request? I do not know, so I have tagged it as both.

I hope this can be fixed, added or resolved before long.

Is anyone else having this issue?